# Ansible - Environment variables setting

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I need to set the environment in the target machine. The environment variables are present in the file called .env337. There are several variables inside that file like

```
export AB_HOME=/tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3  #/gcc3p32   # for 32-bit
export PATH=${AB_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I have tried the below playbook to set the environment and register the environment variables in order to use them in the environment keyword to run the other commands in the registered environment, but it didn't worked.

```
- hosts: dev
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: To set the environment
      shell: . ./.env337
      register: output
```

Is there any other way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Set the environment and register the environment variables in order to use them in the environment keyword to run the other commands."*

A: The environment variables set in the `shell` command can not be persistent. The shell process will be terminated after the execution of the command(s). For example

```
    - shell: |
        cat ./.env337
        . ./.env337
        echo "AB_HOME = $AB_HOME"
        echo "PATH = $PATH"
        exit 0
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines

    - shell: |
        echo "AB_HOME = $AB_HOME"
        echo "PATH = $PATH"
        exit 0
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
```

give

```
    "result.stdout_lines": [
        "export AB_HOME=/tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3  #/gcc3p32   # for 32-bit", 
        "export PATH=${AB_HOME}/bin:${PATH}", 
        "", 
        "AB_HOME = /tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3", 
        "PATH = /tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/admin/bin"
    ]

    "result.stdout_lines": [
        "AB_HOME = ", 
        "PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/admin/bin"
    ]
```

As expected the variables are missing in the second `shell` task.

---

> Q: *"what if I don't know what are all the variables present inside the env file. Is there any other way to print all variables instead of using echo."*

A: Short answer: Create a dictionary `env_dict_add` with the environment variables. Use it in the `shell` module to create the environment `environment: "{{ env_dict_add }}"`.

Details

1) Create a list of unknown variables. For example

```
    - shell: cat ./.env337
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        env_list: "{{ env_list|default([]) +
                      [item.split('=').0.split(' ').1|trim] }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    - debug:
        var: env_list
```

gives

```
    "env_list": [
        "AB_HOME", 
        "PATH"
    ]
```

2) Create a dictionary with the environment. For example

```
    - shell: |
        . ./.env337
        set
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        env_dict: "{{ env_dict|default({})|
                      combine({my_key: my_value}) }}"
      vars:
        my_key: "{{ item.split('=').0 }}"
        my_value: "{{ item.split('=').1|default('') }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

3) Use any environment variable from the dictionary. For example, print whatever variables have been exported by sourcing the file `.env337`

```
    - debug:
        msg: "var: {{ item }} value: {{ env_dict[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ env_list }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": "var: AB_HOME value: /tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3"

    "msg": "var: PATH value: /tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/admin/bin"
```

4) Create a dictionary with the additional environment variables only. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        env_dict_add: "{{ env_dict_add|default({})|
                          combine({item: env_dict[item]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ env_list }}"
    - debug:
        var: env_dict_add
```

gives

```
    "env_dict_add": {
        "AB_HOME": "/tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3", 
        "PATH": "/tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/admin/bin"
    }
```

5) Use the dictionary `env_dict_add` to create environment variables in the shell command. For example

```
    - shell: echo ${{ item }}
      loop: "{{ env_list }}"
      register: result
      environment: "{{ env_dict_add }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(result.results|json_query('[].[item, stdout]')) }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": {
        "AB_HOME": "/tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3", 
        "PATH": "/tl/dev/abinitio/abinitio-V3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/admin/bin"
    }
```